# ECS Task Definition Error not support sourcePath

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, datadog

I have a problem i would like to set a task to my ECS but I get the following error.

Error: creating ECS Task Definition (project-datadog): ClientException: Fargate compatible task definitions do not support sourcePath

My TF File :

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "datadog" {
  family                   = "project-datadog-ecs"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  cpu                      = "2048"
  memory                   = "8192"
  execution_role_arn       = aws_iam_role.ecs_tasks_execution_role.arn
  container_definitions    = file("${path.module}/datadog-agent-ecs-logs.json")
    volume {
          host_path = "/var/run/docker.sock"
          name = "docker_sock"
        }
    volume {
          host_path = "/proc/"
          name = "proc"
        }
    volume {
          host_path = "/sys/fs/cgroup/"
          name = "cgroup"
        }
    volume {
          host_path = "/opt/datadog-agent/run"
          name = "pointdir"
        }

      volume {
          host_path = "/var/lib/docker/containers/"
          name = "containers_root"
        }

  tags = local.mandatory_tags
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "datadog" {
  name            = "project-datadog"
  cluster         = module.ecs_cluster.cluster_id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.datadog.arn
  desired_count = 1

  tags = local.mandatory_tags
}
```

JSON FILE (datadog-agent-ecs-logs.json):

```
[
      {
        "name": "datadog-agent",
        "image": "public.ecr.aws/datadog/agent:latest",
        "cpu": 100,
        "memory": 512,
        "essential": true,
        "healthCheck": {
            "retries": 3,
            "command": ["CMD-SHELL","agent health"],
            "timeout": 5,
            "interval": 30,
            "startPeriod": 15
          },
        "mountPoints": [
          {
            "containerPath": "/var/run/docker.sock",
            "sourceVolume": "docker_sock",
            "readOnly": null
          },
          {
            "containerPath": "/host/sys/fs/cgroup",
            "sourceVolume": "cgroup",
            "readOnly": null
          },
          {
            "containerPath": "/host/proc",
            "sourceVolume": "proc",
            "readOnly": null
          },
          {
            "containerPath": "/opt/datadog-agent/run",
            "sourceVolume": "pointdir",
            "readOnly": false
          },
          {
            "containerPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers",
            "sourceVolume": "containers_root",
            "readOnly": true
          }
        ],
        "environment": [
          {
            "name": "DD_API_KEY",
            "value": "API"
          },
          {
            "name": "DD_SITE",
            "value": "SITE"
          },
          {
            "name": "DD_LOGS_ENABLED",
            "value": "true"
          },
          {
            "name": "DD_LOGS_CONFIG_CONTAINER_COLLECT_ALL",
            "value": "true"
          }
        ]
    }
]
```

When i remove requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"] i have this problem

Task definition does not support launch_type FARGATE.

Has someone already had this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to map volumes into a Fargate container that map to paths on the host server. The host server is completely unavailable to you when you are deploying with Fargate, so you can't possibly map volumes that specify a `host_path` value to Fargate containers.

The way you are trying to use DataDog here, simply does not make sense for an ECS Fargate deployment. The configuration would only make sense for an ECS EC2 deployment.

Comment: Ok I think I understand
What could be the solution to put the volumes in the json? And if i delete the fargate i have the problem too :'(

Comment: You are configuring DataDog to monitor the docker service running on the host server. You can't do that at all on Fargate, because the host server is also being used to run other AWS customer's Fargate containers, and it is completely restricted from your accessing it. What you are trying to do makes no sense. The "solution" is to simply not do this at all. The entire thing you are trying to do will never work on Fargate.

Comment: I took the solution from the datadog site:
https://docs.datadoghq.com/fr/containers/amazon_ecs/logs/?tab=linux
This should normally be possible

Comment: No, it is **NOT** possible with ECS on Fargate. It is **ONLY** possible with ECS on EC2. There is separate documentation for Fargate: https://docs.datadoghq.com/fr/integrations/ecs_fargate/?tab=fluentbitetfirelens

Comment: Thanks it's worked. 
I had the wrong documentation